# Cannot submit a form in AngularJS to Server

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and I got a beta project to modify the exisiting model. I cannot post the below form through api. When i click on submit button, the dasboard is senseless. can some one guide me how to move further. This is Angular version:1.6.0. I have passed the ng-submit as startApproval in form element.. But it doesn't workout

> index.html

```
<form ng-controller="RequestController" method="post" ng-submit="startApproval()">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row" ng-submit>
    <p class="text-info">Please create request...</p>
    <!-- Left -->
    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Request</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- process type -->
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="generic_process_id">Select process typ:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="generic_process_id" ng-model="request.approvalObject.generic_process_id" >

              <option value="1"  ng-show="true" >Simple Process</option>
                <!--   <option ng-hide= "true" ng-disabled="true" value="2">2</option>
                <option ng-hide= "true" ng-disabled= "true" value="3">3</option>
                <option ng-hide= "true" ng-disabled= "true" value="4">4</option>-->
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Priority</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- priority type -->
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <label>Select priority:</label><br>
            <div class="btn-group" ng-init="request.approvalObject.priority='1'">
              <label class="btn btn-info" ng-model="request.approvalObject.priority" uib-btn-radio="'1'" uncheckable>Low</label>
              <label class="btn btn-info" ng-model="request.approvalObject.priority" uib-btn-radio="'2'" uncheckable>High</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Center -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- Description part-->
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Description</h4>
        </div>
        <pre>{{request.approvalObject|json}}</pre>
        <pre>{{request.form|json}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!-- value part-->
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Value</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" name="value" ng-model="request.approvalObject.value"><b class="text-primary">{{request.approvalObject.value_currency}}</b>
            </label>

          <br>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Approver</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="groups list list-insert">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First approver name" name="approver1_name" ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver1_name">
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- show second approver if process type != 1 -->
          <div ng-show="secondApprover"  class="groups list list-insert">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Second approver name" name="approver2_name" ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver2_name" >
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="request">

</form>
```

> Controller.js

```
'use strict';

export default class RequestController {


  approvalObject = {};


  form = {};

  secondApprover = false;



$onInit() {
  this.approvalObject.generic_process_id=1;
  this.approvalObject.value_currency="EUR";
  this.approvalObject.priority=1;


  this.form.type=1;
}

  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($http, $scope, socket) {
    this.$http = $http;
    console.log("testentry");
  }


  startApproval(approvalObject) {
    console.log("test");
    // creator_email and name from backend
    approvalObject.generic_process_id=1;
    approvalObject.creator_email= "test1@example.com";
    approvalObject.creator_name= "test1";
    approvalObject.approver1_email= approvalObject.approver1_name+"@example.com";
    approvalObject.approver2_email= approvalObject.approver2_name+"@example.com";

    // wip from backend
    approvalObject.approval_process_status= "wip";
    approvalObject.priority= "super high";
    //date_of_creation: '',  -->> filled by database
    approvalObject.date_of_expiration = undefined;
    approvalObject.sending_tool= "Web-App";
    approvalObject.submitRequest=true;

    this.$http.post('/api/approvals', approvalObject);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startApproval(approvalObject)method in your controller expecting input parametar object. but you are calling with out passing any object to the function on ng-submit in your html

you can clear the input parameter in your controller and you can access thos variables in funtion with 'this'keyword like

this.approvalObject.generic_process_id=1;